# Mysql ORDER BY FIELD() in specific pattern

Tags: mysql

if anyone please help me , i am struck with it..
sorry for my bad english
My sql query is:-

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(ID,1,5,4,3)
```

**I want to do this id 1 should be first record, id 5 should be 6th record, id 4 should be 11th record and id 3 should be 16th record,
Is there a way to do this in mysql..
Please help me.**

Answer (score 0):

Your Code should work as long as you only want to view the IDs listed in the order by clause. Try to add the ID you are selecting to the where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE ID in(1,3,4,5)
ORDER BY FIELD(ID,1,5,4,3) ;
```

Could you test it? It is working fine for me.

You can also solve this problem with multiple selects and union.

```
SELECT * FROM table where ID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table where ID=5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table where ID=4
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table where ID=3  ;
```

UNION ALL will show a complete resultset. UNION without ALL will exclude duplicate results. In your case duplicates are impossible, so union without ALL would suffice :

```
 SELECT * FROM table where ID=1
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM table where ID=5
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM table where ID=4
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM table where ID=3  ;
```