# Error in "ORDER BY FIELD"

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query in MYSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MeasurementRowIndex, X, Y, Z 
FROM GeneralResultsTable 
WHERE MainDataIndex IN (1, 2) 
ORDER BY FIELD(MeasurementRowIndex , 2, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6, 5)
```

and I get:

> 'FIELD' is not recognized built-in function name.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share me your table structure

Comment: Error message says it all - `FIELD()` is not a function. You are coming from a different RDBMS background, you can't use the same syntax.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by using the word `FIELD` there?

Comment: Make sure FIELD is available as a fuinction in your version of mysql ,then see this duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523147/mysql-order-by-field-in-specific-pattern?rq=1

Comment: I want to order the table by a given order, so that in the following example, the second row becomes the first, the fourth row becomes the second and so on...

Comment: @Mjh See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html Specifically the `FIELD()` function

Comment: @Mjh are you talking about the MySQL [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function?

Comment: Use field name not FIELD

Comment: @AvinashKumarSingh My table looks like:

MainDataIndex MeasurementRowIndex SiteNumber X Y Z
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 2 1 1 1
1 2 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 1 1 1
2 3 1 1 1 1
2 3 2 1 1 1
2 4 1 1 1 1
2 4 2 1 1 1

Comment: @RiggsFolly - correct, my mistake, I'll leave the comment so others can learn not to jump to conclusions like I did. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently the documentation of older versions is not available on the official site any more but I found it mirrored here: http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_field. It seems the function was implemented since the beginning.

Comment: @user3584783 I have change my answer please try it

Comment: @AvinashKumarSingh Do you mean that I'll write "MeasurementRowIndex" instead of "FIELD"? Because if so, I got the same error: 
'MeasurementRowIndex' is not recognized built-in....

Comment: @user3584783 Please share GeneralResultsTable.sql file so I can try to find any solutions.

Comment: @AvinashKumarSingh How do I do that?

Comment: Please share me file using skype my skype id is avinash26dec1.

Answer (score 0):

If FIELD() is not available in your version of MySQL then you'll have to interpret the MeasurementRowIndex and convert it to a number that ascends:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MeasurementRowIndex, X, Y, Z FROM GeneralResultsTable WHERE MainDataIndex IN (1, 2) 
ORDER BY CASE MeasurementRowIndex 
  WHEN 2 THEN 1 
  WHEN 4 THEN 2 
  WHEN 3 THEN 3 
  WHEN 1 THEN 4 
  WHEN 7 THEN 5 
  WHEN 8 THEN 6 
  WHEN 6 THEN 7 
  WHEN 5 THEN 8 
END
```

Comment: @axiac It's available in all versions, it just cannot be used to do what you are attempting to use it for

Comment: I can't, because I rarely use MySQL and I don't recognise the function.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT MeasurementRowIndex, X, Y, Z, FIELD(MeasurementRowIndex , 2, 
4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6, 5) 
FROM GeneralResultsTable 
WHERE MainDataIndex IN (1, 2) 
ORDER BY FIELD(MeasurementRowIndex , 2, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6, 5)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT MeasurementRowIndex, X, Y, Z, FIELD(MeasurementRowIndex , 2, 
4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6, 5) 
FROM GeneralResultsTable 
WHERE MainDataIndex IN (1, 2) 
ORDER BY FIELD(MeasurementRowIndex , 2, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6, 5)
```